# Infinite number of ways to write $1=\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{a_1}+\cdots+\frac{1}{a_k}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math

How can I show that there is an infinite number of ways in which $1$ can be written in the form $$1=\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{a_1}+\cdots+\frac{1}{a_k},$$ where $n>1$ is an integer (this number is fixed), each $a_i$ is an integer and $n<a_1<\cdots<a_k.$

I don't know what to do.. 
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Hint**: For any integer $a_k > 1$, we have $\dfrac{1}{a_k} = \dfrac{1}{a_k+1} + \dfrac{1}{a_k^2+a_k}$, where $a_k+1 < a_k^2+a_k$.

So, if $1 = \dfrac{1}{n}+\dfrac{1}{a_1}+\cdots+\dfrac{1}{a_{k-1}}+\dfrac{1}{a_k}$ for some integers $n < a_1 < \cdots < a_{k-1} < a_k$, then we also have $1 = \dfrac{1}{n}+\dfrac{1}{a_1}+\cdots+\dfrac{1}{a_{k-1}}+\dfrac{1}{a_k+1} + \dfrac{1}{a_k^2+a_k}$, where $n < a_1 < \cdots < a_{k-1} < a_k+1 < a_k^2+a_k$.

You should be able to finish the proof from this.